# Why are Streams faster than ForkJoinPool in MergeSort?

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, mergesort, java-stream

I am working on my master's thesis, in which I compare different Java concurrency mechanisms. From tests that I've run it seems that Java 8 streams are **faster** in mergesort algorithm than Java 7 ForkJoinPool mechanism, which was created with divide and conquer problems in mind.

What is the deal?

What is under the hood of the Streams that makes it go faster?

How can I explain better performance of Streams when ForkJoin supposed to be the best choice in those kind of cases.

Here are my results (milions of elements/time in seconds):

```
+-----+---------+--------------+
|     | Streams | ForkJoinPool |
+-----+---------+--------------+
| 1M  | 0.172s  | 0.182s       |
| 2M  | 0.36s   | 0.346s       |
| 3M  | 0.547s  | 0.713s       |
| 4M  | 0.746s  | 0.618s       |
| 5M  | 0.95s   | 1.193s       |
| 6M  | 1.206s  | 1.078s       |
| 7M  | 1.362s  | 1.324s       |
| 8M  | 1.636s  | 1.416s       |
| 9M  | 1.874s  | 1.705s       |
| 10M | 2.133s  | 2.858s       |
+-----+---------+--------------+
```

And here is the stream I am using:

```
  public static void sort(int[] numbers) {
     int N = numbers.length;
     int[] temp = new int[N];
     IntStream.range(1, N)
        .filter(n -> (n & -n) == n) // power of 2
        .flatMap(n -> IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2 * n)
        .limit((N - n) / (2 * n) + 1)
        .parallel()
        .map(i -> merge(numbers, temp, i, i + n - 1, Math.min(i + n + n - 1, N - 1))))
    .toArray();
  }
```

and merge method:

```
private static void merge(int[] a, int[] temp, int low, int mid, int high) {
    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
      temp[i] = a[i];
    }
    int i = low, j = mid + 1;
    for (int k = low; k <= high; k++) {
      if (i > mid) {
        a[k] = temp[j++];
      } else if (j > high) {
        a[k] = temp[i++];
      } else if (temp[i] < temp[j]) {
        a[k] = temp[i++];
      } else {
        a[k] = temp[j++];
      }
    }
}
```

ForkJoinPool main method:

```
@Override
protected void compute() {
  final int range = end - start;
  if (range > blockSize) {
    final int midPoint = start + (range / 2);
    final ForkingAction left = new ForkingAction(start, midPoint, blockSize);
    left.fork();
    final ForkingAction right = new ForkingAction(midPoint + 1, end, blockSize);
    right.compute();
    left.join();
    merge(start, end);
  } else {
    sortSeq(start, end);
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably you're not doing micro benchmarkin in the right way.

Comment: Please provide the code you're using to sort?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I added the code for ForkJoinPool compute() method

Comment: And how are you sorting the stream?

Comment: @LouisWasserman added more code. It should be clear now.

Comment: Your stream function seems to be essentially nonsensical.  `Stream.map` doesn't really make sense the way you've used it, it's only supposed to be used for pure functions that transform the data.  I can't even tell what it's doing in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a join() in the FJP version. Join() in Java7 creates continuation threads while the joining thread waits for the join to complete. In Java8, the thread just waits.

Stream uses the CountedCompleter class which doesn't use join(). I've been writing a continuing critique of this framework since 2011. The article for Java8 is [here](http://coopsoft.com/ar/Calamity2Article.html) If you replace RecursiveTask with CountedCompleter then you should get better results. Using the CountedCompeter class is difficult at best.